# I am trying to create an API for a web app

Tags: python, fastapi

I have started to code in Python as I saw in some of the available tutorials. I have pip installed fastapi and "uvicorn[standard]" on vscode, when I try to import the fastapi (from fastapi import FastAPI) it gives me an error of:

> Import ""fastapi" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)".

Could you also help me and provide me some good tutorials for the same.

I expected for it to import it so I could start building my API